# Is there any alternative attribute for dir=auto in IE

Tags: php, html

We have to show some text which may be in English or Arabic in Page. we are facing problem with text direction.

For English the direction will be left-to-right, for Arabic the direction would be right-to-left. We have added 'dir=auto' in  to do this thing dynamically. [Means based on the content language the direction will be changed]

```
Exp :
<table>
<tr>
<th>english text</th>
<th>arabic text</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td dir=auto><span>love</span></td>
<td dir=auto><span >حبحبحب</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

These change working perfectly with Firefox and Chrome. But IE doesn’t support this attribute and it is challenging us to find some alternative way to do.

So, our question is, how to change the text direction 'left-to-right' / 'right-to-left' based on content (IE)?

We appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately support for HTML5's `dir="auto"` is still very limited. However you ought to try to avoid it, as this "auto-detection" is crude by design and should be used only as a last resort. Perhaps this is a good opportunity to refine your requirements, and avoid the upcoming technical debt entirely.

Comment: It should be possible to write a polyfill in Javascript (a quick search didn't find any).  But then users which block Javascript will see wrong bidi.  It'd be safer to write a server-side polyfill (in PHP?) — unless you're also dynamically creating elements with dir=auto in the browser...  (Server-side also requires well-formed markup or a good tag soup parser.)

Comment: As for trying to avoid it: I'm not convinced dir=auto is evil (if only it were well supported...), but one thing clearly worth doing if these texts are user-submitted is [receiving and storing the direction](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir#reportingdirection) — otherwise when users had to manually change the input direction (e.g. Ctrl+Shift on windows) this information will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Because at least IE 11 doesn't support `dir="auto"` correctly, I wrote the following helper method:

```
/**
 * Helper to determine if text is LTR text.
 * We assume that any left-to-right text contains at least one character from a to z,
 * or ONLY the following characters: # _ [any alphanumeric character, including digits]
 *
 * @param {string} string
 *
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isLtr(string) {
  return string.match(/[a-z]+|^[\#\w]+$/gi) !== null;
}
```

Using that helper, I check every element's text and manually set `dir="rtl"` as you can see in this simplified example:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.element-with-dir-auto');
var text = '#حبحبحب';

if (!isLtr(text)) {
  element.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
}
```

You might have to adjust the helper method's regular expression to better cover your relevant cases.

Comment: What about Spanish accents, Emoji, non-breaking-space, line breaks, and the thousands of other Unicode characters which have to be taken into account? Also, what about a page written in an ltr language that describes an rtl language? There are just simply too many thing wrong with this solution for it to ever be practically workable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try guessing text direction according to charcodes.

If at least 50% of string is filled with RTL symbols, then the string is in RTL text direction.

```
// Some helper function
function isNumberInRanges(number, ranges) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; ++i)
      if (number >= +ranges[i][0] && number <= +ranges[i][1])
        return true;

    return false;
}

function guessTextDirection(text) {
    /*
    * https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp
    * [?] Non-letter symbolic ranges: 0..64, 91..96, 123..126, 127, 128..159, 160..191, 247, 8592..8703, 8704..8959, ...
    * [LTR] Cyrillic, latin, greek, etc letters: 65..90, 97..122, 256..383, 384..591, 768..879, 880..1023, 1024..1279, 1280..1327
    * [RTL] Arabic, Hebrew, etc letters: 1470..1920 (in facebook's humble opinion)
    */

    text = text.trim();

    var symbolsCounter = {
      ltr: 0,
      rtl: 0
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
      var keyCode = text.charCodeAt(i);

      switch (true) {
        case (isNumberInRanges(keyCode, [[1470, 1920]])):
          // this is rtl symbol
          symbolsCounter.rtl++;
          break;
        case (isNumberInRanges(keyCode, [[65, 90], [97, 122], [256, 591], [768, 1327]])):
          // this is ltr symbol
          symbolsCounter.ltr++;
          break;
          // otherwise, this is non-letter symbol, omitting it
      }
    }

    if (symbolsCounter.ltr > symbolsCounter.rtl) {
      return 'ltr';
    } else if (symbolsCounter.ltr < symbolsCounter.rtl) {
      return 'rtl';
    }

    return '';
}
```

Usage:

```
var label = document.querySelector('.some-label');
label.setAttribute('dir', guessTextDirection(label.textContent));
```

P.S. method can be optimized, and, I believe, needs some sort of benchmark test ;)

Answer (score -3):

Here you go. Use this css for elements; but You need to identify the lang first.

```
.rtl {
    direction: rtl; 
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

.ltr {
    direction: ltr; 
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;    
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/hD5Sp/)

Comment: Instead of adding extra classes, you could use the attribute selector on lang instead – `[lang=en] { … }` (although this will of course not work in older browsers that don’t know the attribute selector).

Comment: The OP is looking for an _automatic_ solution.

Comment: `bidi-override` is undesired here (and almost everywhere).  It'll force *all* characters to be ordered RTL or LTR, effectively inhibiting the bidi algorithm.  In `.rtl` English text and numbers would also go RTL, in `.ltr` arabic text would also go LTR :-(  OP wants the implicit algorithm to work, just to set the algorithm's *base direction* correctly.